# TypeScript: ReturnType -> How to set the return type of function returned by a function

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am using graphql codegen to generate the types for my GraphQL codebase. A sample code of the core sdk generated looks like this

```
export function getSdk(client: GraphQLClient, withWrapper: SdkFunctionWrapper = defaultWrapper) {
  return {
   myCustomFunction(...): Promise<MyFuncReturn>
 }
}
```

getSdk returns an object of all the API's I have defined for my GraphQL Server.

I am trying to use ReturnType syntax to match the return value of myCustomFunction i.e. MyFuncReturn in other parts of the code. Reason being, many of my queries / output response objects are incomplete (I dont want all the fields for all the queries) and hence I cant typecast it to the complete response object defined in the schema.

I want to leverage ReturnType to such that my other parts of the code can just leverage the returntype of the function rather than knowing what object / type is being returned, something like:

```
mytestCode {

    callCoreSdk(): ReturnType<getSdk().myCustomFunc>
}
```

Is this possible and allowed. Tried the above and getting error. Also, could not locate examples where I can use ReturnType for a func inside a func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off, but it can be done. To get the type of `getSdk` you need to use the `typeof` operator (`typeof getSdk`). Then can use `ReturnType` to get the return type of `getSdk` (`ReturnType<typeof getSdk>`). To get the type of a property in the return type you can use an [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) (`ReturnType<typeof getSdk>['myCustomFunction']`)

```
export function getSdk() {
  return {
    myCustomFunction(a: string): Promise<MyFuncReturn> { return null! }
 }
}

interface mytestCode {
    callCoreSdk(): ReturnType<typeof getSdk>['myCustomFunction']
}

declare var x: mytestCode;
x.callCoreSdk()("")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=20&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwEoWIgTsqAvFAM7A4CWyA5gLABQEAHmAPY7BQBmKqw5L+KlgDKAEwDWACgCUUAN70oUHFlz4FdJUoC2IAMKJSLbUjR8BkgIYAuEmUpVptgAo5j5YhAA8cUxlV4AHzyygH4yIgANpEAhFAAvoqJdMn0lMAQOJyWqNC6GaR6LKLQGlpQqJbRRSpiUk5QmNh4ACrg3qCQLJxQQsB1gQDaAOS6BkYmPObIwwC69Kl0JaiRlipQAG5rUIy2+RCFxRAA3PSMAHSV1WwQdTKSAEQP0kA)